# Scala - max function wrong result being returned

Tags: scala

The `max` function given below return last value of last element of list and not the max (I've added a few extra `println`s for debug purposes)

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def loop(largest: Int, ys: List[Int]): Int = {
    println("ys: " + ys)
    println("largest: " + largest)
    if(!ys.isEmpty) {
      println("ys.head: " + ys.head + "\n")
      if (largest >= ys.head)
        loop(largest, ys.tail)
      else ys.head
        loop(ys.head, ys.tail)
    }
    else largest
  }
  loop(xs.head, xs.tail)
}
```

Console output for `scala> max(List(1,2,3,1,2))`

```
ys: List(2, 3, 1, 2)
largest: 1
ys.head: 2

ys: List(3, 1, 2)
largest: 2
ys.head: 3

ys: List(1, 2)
largest: 3
ys.head: 1

ys: List(2)
largest: 3
ys.head: 2

ys: List()
largest: 3 // shouldn't it just end here?
ys: List()
largest: 2
ys: List(2)
largest: 1
ys.head: 2

ys: List()
largest: 2
res0: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` expression should be:

```
if (largest >= ys.head)
    loop(largest, ys.tail)
else
    loop(ys.head, ys.tail)
```

Your code is currently the same as:

```
val result = if (largest >= ys.head)
                 loop(largest, ys.tail)
             else ys.head

loop(ys.head, ys.tail)
```

so you are throwing away the result of the recursive call and then returning `loop(ys.head, ys.tail)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! It was a typo, I read the code 3-4 times but couldn't catch it, I think this is what happens when you start a new language :)

Comment: @Sourabh - Yes, it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 3):

Look more carefully, how `else` part looks like:

```
else ys.head
  loop(ys.head, ys.tail)
```

it does not make much sense :) This one should be correct:

```
else loop(ys.head, ys.tail)
```

But in this case I would rather use a pattern match:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def loop(largest: Int, ys: List[Int]): Int = ys match {
    case y :: rest if y > largest => loop(y, rest)
    case y :: rest => loop(largest, rest)
    case _ => largest
  }

  loop(xs.head, xs.tail)
}
```

I find it a little bit easier to read and analyse and (arguably) it will make it harder to make this kind of mistake

Comment: Thanks! I am a Scala begginer so I don't know what pattern match is but I will read about it asap!

Answer (score 0):

One of the numerous approaches to obtain the max value of a list relies on sorting the list  and then taking the first (or last) element; for instance

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = (xs sortWith {_>_}) (0)
```

In this function, `sortWith` may be replaced with a call to an implementation of QuickSort.

Take a look at https://jazzy.id.au/default/2012/10/16/benchmarking_scala_against_java.html for a non-idiomatic Scala implementation of QuickSort and benchmarking against Java and idiomatic approaches.

Comment: Isn't sorting too much work for finding max? A simple iteration of whole array/list would be faster, right?

Comment: Good point @Sourabh; the suggested idea takes into account that QuickSort worst case is O(n2) for a fully sorted list though a prechecking of this makes the worst case O(n), linear to the number of entries in the list; however, QuickSort average case is O(n log n). This may be of interest when processing large lists.